# Did Austro-Hungarian emperor literally wear two crowns?

Tags: monarchy, austria-hungary

From George Antonius' *The Arab Awakening*:

> The Arab provinces were to form a single
> kingdom with its own parliament and local government, and
> with Arabic as the language of its institutions; the kingdom
> was to be part of a Turco-Arab empire, similar in architecture to the Austro-Hungarian edifice; and the Ottoman
> sultan in Constantinople would wear, in addition to his own
> Turkish crown, the crown of the Arab kingdom, as the Hapsburg emperor in Vienna wore the crown of Hungary.

In what sense did the Hapsburg emperor wear two crowns? Is it meant in figurative sense, or was there a specific court protocol, assuring that the emperor equally honored the two kingdoms?

**Remark**
Obviously, it is physically unlikely that Austro-Hungarian emperor literally wore two crowns in the same time. So the question is more about the court protocol, assuring that the two kingdoms would be treated equally - I assume that would be especially relevant when meeting foreign ambassadors or other monarchs.

As far as my research goes at this point - [the Emperor and the Empress had to be crowned in Budapest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronation_of_the_Hungarian_monarch#Matthias_Church_in_Budapest) in order to be legally considered rulers of Hungary - [Franz-Joseph and Elizabeth in Bavaria were crowned in Budapest after the Compromise with Hungary](https://www.habsburger.net/en/chapter/austro-hungarian-dual-monarchy-coronation-hungarian-royal-couple), whereas [Charles IV and Zita of Bourbon-Parma were crowned in Budapest and in Croatia shortly after their accession to the Austrian throne.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_I_of_Austria#Trialism_and_Croatia)

[image]
[Franz Joseph I crowned with the Holy Crown as the King of Hungary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Crown_of_Hungary)

[image]
[Imperial Crown, Orb, and Sceptre of Austria, displayed in the Imperial Treasury at the Hofburg Palace in Vienna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_Crown_of_Austria)

**Alternative path**
Since no one seems to come up with the protocol details of Austro-Hungarian court, I suggest a simpler path to tackling this question: have the two crowns ever been in the same country/town/building ?

Comment: One for each head :-O

Comment: @SJuan76 [not unheard of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-headed_eagle)

Answer (score 4):

There exist portraits of [Franz Joseph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz_Joseph_I_of_Austria) wearing the [Austrian crown](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_Crown_of_Austria) as well as portraits with the [Hungarian crown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Crown_of_Hungary) ([example](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Koron%C3%A1z%C3%A1s_Bud%C3%A1n.jpg))

, but in most portraits he actually does not wear any crown.

I do not think it would have been physically possible to wear both crowns at the same time and still look as dignified as would have been politically necessary.

Comment: I thought more about alternating them during certain ceremonies or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

This is a figure of speech; the *Kaiser und König* did not literally wear two hats at the same time.

This is referring to the [dual monarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austria-Hungary), proclaimed after the [Hungarians revolted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_Revolution_of_1848) and demanded autonomy. Prior to that compromise, there was one crown in the Austrian Empire - the crown of Austria*. One of the [compromises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austro-Hungarian_Compromise_of_1867) the Hungarians won was the restoration of their kingdom *within* the Empire (in the same way that the Kingdom of Bohemia was a kingdom within the Holy Roman Empire).

However, the king of Hungary would be the same person who was the emperor of Austria. Hence, two crowns. These were *two separate roles* - there wasn't a title of "Emperor of Austria-Hungary" but "King of Hungary" and "Emperor of Austria" were both roles that just happened to be held by the same person.

--

* Strictly speaking, Hungary was held in personal union before that point, so the Austrian Emperor still had two crowns

Comment: Weren't there any particularities of protocol, like being crowned twice (in Austria and in Hungary). How would be the foreign visitors/ambassadors received without bias towards one of the kingdoms?